# How can I highlight a label when click in a radio button?

Tags: html, css

I want to highlight the label of a radio button when a I click in it, I find [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label) but don't work. Here my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="same-line">
    <input type="checkbox" name="417-jornadas-de-g%c3%a9nero-sin-fecha-confirmada" value="Sí" class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox">
    Jornadas de género (sin fecha confirmada)</label>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
</div> 
<div class="same-line">
    <input type="checkbox" name="417-curso-de-fotograf%c3%ada-sin-fecha-confirmada" value="Sí" class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox">
    Curso de fotografía (sin fecha confirmada)</label>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.same-line input[type='radio'] {
    display:none;
}

.same-line label[class='checkbox'] {
    display:inline-block;
        font-size: 12.2pt;
}

.same-line input[type='radio']:checked + label[class='checkbox'] { 
   background-color: #FFBF00 !important;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Oh, that was *my* answer `:)`

Comment: What browser did you test this in?

Comment: you don't have any radio buttons, do you mean checkboxes?

Comment: Yes @ŠimeVidas, therefore I put the link to the q/a, for a most clearly situation.
Paul, I use Chrome 20.

Comment: @Distriker Do you want check-boxes or radio-buttons?

Comment: I'm stupid... I made a huge mistake but idiot, that is accompanied by fatigue. Well friends, I confused radio buttons with checkboxes... yes... I don't know how...

I think, that I must to go to sleep, many hours awake. Thanks and sorry :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

(I've added `id` attributes on the check-boxes, and `for` attributes on the labels)

```
<div class="same-line">
    <input type="checkbox" name="417-jornadas-de-g%c3%a9nero-sin-fecha-confirmada" id="cb1" value="Sí" class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="cb1">
    Jornadas de género (sin fecha confirmada)</label>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
</div>
<div class="same-line">
    <input type="checkbox" name="417-curso-de-fotograf%c3%ada-sin-fecha-confirmada" id="cb2" value="Sí" class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="cb2">
    Curso de fotografía (sin fecha confirmada)</label>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

(I've changed "radio" to "checkbox")

```
.same-line input[type='checkbox'] {
    display:none;
}

.same-line label.checkbox {
    display:inline-block;
        font-size: 12.2pt;
}

.same-line input[type='checkbox']:checked + label.checkbox { 
   background-color: #FFBF00;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PUcmA/1/

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/hekh8/

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ background-color: #FFFF00; } ​
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="same-line">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="417-jornadas-de-g%c3%a9nero-sin-fecha-confirmada" value="Sí" class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox1">
    Jornadas de género (sin fecha confirmada)</label>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
</div> 
<div class="same-line">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="417-curso-de-fotograf%c3%ada-sin-fecha-confirmada" value="Sí" class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox2">
    Curso de fotografía (sin fecha confirmada)</label>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.same-line input[type='checkbox'] {
    display:none;
}

.same-line label {
    display:inline-block;
        font-size: 12.2pt;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.same-line input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
   background-color: #ddd;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heZBT/