# Change Style of Selected Radio Button Label

Tags: css, radio-button, label

I'm attempting to change the border color of a radio button label when it is selected in the form. I found this question which is pretty much exactly what I am looking to do: [CSS - How to Style a Selected Radio Buttons Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label) but when I try it with my own code the color doesn't change on select. This is driving me nuts, I can't figure out why it won't apply the border color - any help is very much appreciated. I have uploaded the code I am working with here: http://jsfiddle.net/SHfr5/ but I will also include it below.

**HTML**

```
<form name="input" action="/engine/preview.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="customizeForm" method="post">
<div id="customize_container">
    <h1>Customize</h1>
    <div id="customize_left">
            <div style="float: left">
            <label for="8dc63f" style="width: 55px;height:55px;background-color:#8dc63f;margin-left:20px;"></label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="8dc63f" value="8dc63f" checked />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left">
            <label for="00aeef" style="width: 55px;height:55px;background-color:#00aeef;border:2px solid #000;margin-left:20px;"></label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="00aeef" value="00aeef" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left">
            <label for="ed1c24" style="width: 55px;height:55px;background-color:#ed1c24;border:2px solid #000;margin-left:20px;"></label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="ed1c24" value="ed1c24" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left">
            <label for="f15a29" style="width: 55px;height:55px;background-color:#f15a29;border:2px solid #000;margin-left:20px;"></label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="color" id="f15a29" value="f15a29" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Preview" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#customize_container {
    width: 840px;
    clear: both;
}

#customize_left {
    width: 385px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

#customizeForm input[type=radio] {
    margin: 5px 0px 40px 43px;
}

#customizeForm label {
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid #000;
}

#customizeForm input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    border: 2px solid #FFF!important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

The issue occurred because of the use of the + CSS selector. The 'adjacent' selector will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this case the label directly preceded by a checked radio button. My original HTML had the label before the input, in order to use the + selector the label must be after the input.