# HTML/CSS - Applying style with css on a single radio button

Tags: html, css

I have 4 radio buttons. 
I want to apply style on one of them (only) - the correct answer:
here is the generated HTML CODE:

```
<p>
<input id="SelectedAnswer" type="radio" value="5" name="SelectedAnswer">
my wrong answer
</p>
<p>
<input id="SelectedAnswer" class="correct-answer" type="radio" value="6" name="SelectedAnswer">
```

my correct answer

and here is my css, which doesn't work:

```
.correct-answer input[type="radio"] {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: a side note: for html to be valid, id should be unique on the page so you should not have multiple `id="selectedAnswer"` attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.correct-answer input[type="radio"]` means radio button having parent element with class `correct-answer`. But, here radio button has class `correct-answer`.

It should be

```
input[type="radio"].correct-answer{}
```

For your information,

you are applying styles such as background-color,color,font-weight. These will not be reflected on radio button.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but it may be worth explaining to the OP *why* it should be that as he doesn't fully understand the CSS rule he originally wrote.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's why nothing works, even with the "right" css. how can I change the style of a radio button - to show it is "the right " answer out of a few ?

Comment: @Dani you want to style radio button?

Comment: @Hiral - I have 4 radio buttons that represents answer to a question - one of the is the correct answer so I want it to be colored differently, so I've added a class="correct-answer" to it's code. but nothing seems to effect it.

Comment: @Dani [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label)