# "Active" state on labeled radio-button?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label

anyone know how to add an active state to the labeled radio-button?

HTML:

```
<label class="blacksize" for="XS">
            <input type="radio" name="comment" value="XS" size="50" required checked>XS<br>
        </label>
        <label class="blacksize">
            <input type="radio" name="comment" value="Small" size="50" required>S<br>
        </label>
        <label class="blacksize">
            <input type="radio" name="comment" value="Medium" size="50" required>M<br>
        </label>
        <label class="blacksize">
            <input type="radio" name="comment" value="Large" size="50" required>L<br>
        </label>
        <label class="blacksize">
            <input type="radio" name="comment" value="XL" size="50" required>XL<br>
        </label>
        <label class="blacksize">
            <input type="radio" name="comment" value="XXL" size="50" required>XXL<br>
        </label>
```

Which CSS-styling can I use to make the selected radio's label have an "active"/"selected" state as you have in menus etc?

LIKE THIS: http://i.cubeupload.com/xURJ8M.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - How to Style a Selected Radio Buttons Label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "checked" try:

```
<input type="radio" name="comment" value="XS" size="50" required checked="checked">
```

Comment: The thing is, i want to style the "label" as I have made the radio button to a "regular" button.. http://i.cubeupload.com/xURJ8M.jpg like that...

Answer (score 0):

For css styles you can just use :checked pseudo class.

```
input[type=radio]:checked {
    box-shadow:red 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

Check out this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/K2Kgf/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio"/>
<label></label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
}
```