# Remove class on radio's that are not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, radio-button

So i have this code

```
<ul id="id_priori">
    <li>
        <label for="id_priori_0">
            <input id="id_priori_0" name="priori" type="radio">Hola
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this code

```
$("#id_tipo").on('click', 'li', function () {
    var self = $(this),
        radio = self.find(":radio")[0];

    radio.checked = !radio.checked;

    self.toggleClass('on', radio.checked);

})
    .find(":radio").each(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('on', this.checked);
});
```

What i want is to unclass all the labels whose radio's arent checked , any idea ?

Comment: Are those radios connected? I mean, can be more than one checked?

Comment: might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(":radio:not(checked)").each(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('on');
});
```

Anyway, assuming all radios are connected, and there is always only one checked, the whole code could be simpler:

```
$("#id_priori").on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', true);
    $(this).addClass('on').siblings().removeClass('on');
});
```

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86PA4/2/). We can work from this point

Comment: It would work , but in my code when i click the li that has the label inside also checks the radio

Comment: if you want, you can have your labels occuping all width of the li: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86PA4/1/)

Comment: Not what i was looking for :/

Comment: does your code work where you click on the radio? I tried to test it on jsfiddle, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I've updated the code to check the radio when you click the li

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean remove all class from each `<label>` add it in the `find`:

```
 .find(":radio").each(function () {
    if( !this.checked){
       $(this).parent('label').removeAttr('class');
    }
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('on', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove class just go with @littleLouito Code
else if you want toggle try this one

```
   $(":radio:not(checked)").each(function () {
      $(this).closest('label').toggleClass("on", this.checked);
    });
```

Comment: Cool but for some reason when i click the label it doesnt does anything , its like if something is canceling it