# Radio button not selectable after styling as a button

Tags: css, haml

I've been trying to style some radio buttons on a form but since styling them, I can't seem to select them...

The CSS I have is:

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
  // text-align: center;
}
.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  color: white;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
}
```

And the radio buttons are (HAML):

```
.form-group
      .col-sm-10.radio-toolbar
        - YearGroup.all.each do |year_group|
          = f.radio_button(:year_group_id, year_group.id)
          = label_tag dom_id(year_group), year_group.name
      = f.label :year_group
```

Any ideas on why I can't select them?

Comment: I don't know if the `for` attribute is set for the label as I am not familiar with `HAML`, but that could be the cause

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I got the CSS from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4642152/4262212

Comment: does your rendered label has `for` attribute, like `<label **for="radio1"**>`?

Comment: Yes, it is <label for='year_group_#id'> (where #id is the id of the year_group)

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity:0` not `display:none`

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  opacity:0; 
  margin: 10px;
  // text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That just hides the radio button but doesn't make the label clickable?