# Styled radio button only allows select of one button

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label/4642152#4642152) and have got the code mostly working, except for the fact that it only ever selects one button, and won't allow selection of the other button...

The code is:

```
.radio-toolbar
        %label{:for => "test_year_group_1"} AS
        %input#test_year_group_1{:name => "test[year_group]", :type => "radio", :value => "1"}
        %label{:for => "test_year_group_2"} A2
        %input#test_year_group_2{:name => "test[year_group]", :type => "radio", :value => "2"}
```

and the css:

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 8px 60px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
}
```

But it only ever selects the A2 button, even when I click on the AS button...does anyone know why?

Comment: Will you create fiddle for it?

Comment: `.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label` expects the label to be after checkbox, you have label first and then the checkbox. So what happens is when you select `AS` its sibling label is given the style which is A2's

Answer (score 0):

As you are using input type to "radio" then it will allow selection of only one button. If you want multiple selection then you can use checkboxes.

Comment: Read this from the Question 
`But it only ever selects the A2 button, even when I click on the AS button...does anyone know why?`.