# Shiny - How to Style a Selected Radio Buttons Label?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label) that was similar, but didn't address the problem when dealing this Radio Buttons in Shiny in their native form; i.e., without HTML.

I have this line:

```
column(6, h1(radioButtons(inputId="gender", "Gender", choices = list("combined" = "combined", "male only" = "male", "female only" = "female"), inline=TRUE)))
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to make the labels (e.g., 'combined', 'male only', 'female only') bold.

I tried setting a class, `class="radioSelect`, as below:

```
column(6, h1(radioButtons(inputId="gender", "Gender", choices = list(class="radioSelect", combined" = "combined", "male only" = "male", "female only" = "female"), inline=TRUE)))
```

...but ended up, amusingly and not surprisingly, with this:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on how I can apply a class to a label on a radio button in Shiny this way? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up changing the R code to put in a class called **radioSelect**:

```
column(6, h1(class="radioSelect", radioButtons(inputId="gender", "Gender", choices = list(...
```

and then in the CSS file, I accessed the labels with:

```
.radioSelect label.radio { ...
```

This worked since the labels all have the class 'radio' on them. Thus I now have control over the labels.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found that this worked to change the style of the entire radioButton input:

```
column(6, h1(radioButtons(inputId="gender", "Gender", choices = list(...)), style = "font-weight:bold;")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="thisForm">
column(6, h1(radioButtons(inputId="gender", "Gender", choices = list(class="radioSelect", combined" = "combined", "male only" = "male", "female only" = "female"), inline=TRUE)))
</div>

CSS
.thisForm{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

At least, that's how it appears to be done here in their documentation: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/radioButtons.html