# how to pull up in css for this following "radio" button for border color,padding,margin etc

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>I have so much left to learn!</div>
  <form action="https://formspree.io/your@email.com" method="POST">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    <br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <br>
    <label for="email">First Name:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <br>
    <label for="iceCream">Are you a cat or dog person?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="iceCream" value="cat" checked>Cat<br>
    <input type="radio" name="iceCream" value="dog">Dog<br>
    <input type="radio" name="iceCream" value="other">Other<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  <a href="www.google.com">Click Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're asking. Are you asking how to apply CSS to your code **in general**? Or is there something specific you're struggling with? You've linked `style.css` -- can you include that please? It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: for specific "radio" button in css ..

Comment: iam confuse only specific to radio button of form into css

Comment: You simply style a radio button with `input[type=radio] { ... }`. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label).

Comment: <label for="iceCream">Are you a cat or dog person?</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="iceCream" value="cat" checked>Cat<br>
    <input type="radio" name="iceCream" value="dog">Dog<br>
    <input type="radio" name="iceCream" value="other">Other<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">  just only this value i have to margin,padding,border,float in css but i cannot make in css..