# Having multiple buttons. Using :active state at the same time

Tags: html, css, button, pseudo-class

```css
.a {
  background-color: white;
}

.a:focus {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="a">1</button>
<button class="a">2</button>
<button class="b">3</button>
<button class="b">4</button>
```

how can i make it so that when i click on a button, its :focus state doesnt disappear unless i click on a button of the same class?
ex in the code above,
if i click on 1, its gonna turn green. if i click on 3, 1 will be green and 3 will be blue.
but if i click on 2 instead of 3, 1 will go back to white and 2 will be green

preferable solution: in html or css

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but it looks like you are trying to replicate the input `type=radio` functionality but with button tags instead. Maybe what you need is to use inputs with `type=radio`, and then style the associated labels as buttons and use the `:checked` pseudo-class instead of `:focus`, using radios with the same `name` (instead of the same `class`) should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [arieljuod's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512238/have-multiple-buttons-have-active-state-at-the-same-time#comment122865145_69512238) above, [`<input>` elements of type radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) work as you describe. You can [define a radio group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group) by "giving each of [the] radio buttons in the group the same [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-name)."

If you are not limited to using `<button>`, `class`, and `:focus`, you can use `<input type="radio">`, `name`, and `:checked`, with `<label>` to help style them like buttons.

Note the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+`, used to match `<span>` only when it immediately follows a checked input.

```css
.radio-button input {
  display: none;
}

.radio-button span {
  padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
  border: 2px outset rgb(118, 118, 118);
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-button input[name="a"]:checked + span {
  background-color: green;
}

.radio-button input[name="b"]:checked + span {
  background-color: blue;
}

.radio-button input[name="c"]:checked + span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="a">
  <span>a1</span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="a">
  <span>a2</span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="b">
  <span>b1</span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="b">
  <span>b2</span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="b">
  <span>b3</span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="c">
  <span>c1</span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
  <input type="radio" name="c">
  <span>c2</span>
</label>
```

Also see:
[How to Style a Selected Radio Buttons Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641752/css-how-to-style-a-selected-radio-buttons-label)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with JavaScript, if you tap on 1 it will turn green, if you tap on 2, 1 will turn white, and 2 will turn green

```js
var buttonA = document.querySelector(".a");
var buttonB = document.querySelector(".b");
var buttonC = document.querySelector(".c");
var buttonD = document.querySelector(".d");
buttonA.style.backgroundColor = "white";
buttonB.style.backgroundColor = "white";
buttonC.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
buttonD.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
buttonA.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (buttonA.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
    buttonA.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else if (buttonA.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    buttonA.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
    buttonA.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
buttonB.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (buttonB.style.backgroundColor == "white" && buttonA.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    buttonB.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    buttonA.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else if (buttonB.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
    buttonB.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else if (buttonB.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    buttonB.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
    buttonB.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
buttonC.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (buttonC.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
    buttonC.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (buttonC.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
    buttonC.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {
    buttonC.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
});
buttonD.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (buttonD.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
    buttonD.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (buttonD.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
    buttonD.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {
    buttonD.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="a">1</button>
<button class="b">2</button>
<button class="c">3</button>
<button class="d">4</button>
```